# How do I add Python support in Vim in Git Bash?

Tags: python, windows, vim, git-bash, msysgit

I want to add Python support in **Vim** in [**Git Bash**](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), how do I do this?

I get false when running:

```
:echo has('python')
```

Comment: very late response but had similar issue. not an answer but an alternative to using Vim in Git Bash, is to use vim_x64 by https://bintray.com/veegee/generic/vim_x64. excellent, picks up whatever python you have on path so works well with conda envs also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TL;DR**: Install **[MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/)** instead, a "superset" of **git bash**, that also comes with a package manager.

---

This ticket shows up [in the `git-for-windows` issue tracker](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/827), and was closed with the following reason:

> This function is not required for Git for Windows to work. In fact, Python is not required for Git for Windows to work, therefore we do not ship it to the end user.
>
> The purpose of Git for Windows is really to bring Git to Windows.
>
> While that implies that we have to ship quite a few Unix-like tools, it does not mean that we will include such tools unless they are needed for Git's own operations, or at least for historical reasons (needs of active contributors are sometimes a factor in deciding whether to include a tool or not).
>
> Having said that, what you really are looking for is [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/). Git for Windows leverages MSYS2 and ships with a subset of its files. MSYS2 even sports a package management system called "pacman" to install more tools (including Git...), so why don't you give it a whirl?

I guess you could go ahead re-install or re-compile vim with Python support, a better course of action seems to be the one suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the path to a `python.exe` in your git bash session

```
# move to $HOME first
cd
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/c/Python27"' > .profile
```

Then Vim will be more likely to detect python.

Make sure to use the latest [git for Windows release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

Comment: AFAICT the msys vim bundled with Git for Windows doesn't want a python.exe, it wants a `msys-python2.7.dll`.

Comment: OK, I'll check that out later, it uses msys2